# No output when printing contents of arraylist

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
/** 
* @author Stephanie Hoyt 
* @version April 10, 2014
*/
public class Purse
{
private ArrayList<MyCoins> coins;
private int total;
/**
 * Default constructor for objects of class Purse.
 */
public Purse()
{
    coins = new ArrayList<MyCoins>();
}

/**
 * Takes Coin as a parameter and adds Coin to the Purse.
 **/
public void add(int coinValue)
{
    coins.add(new MyCoins(coinValue));
    total += coinValue;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public int getTotal()
{
    return total;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void showCoins()
{
    coins = new ArrayList<MyCoins>();
    Iterator<MyCoins> itr = coins.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            MyCoins c = itr.next();
            System.out.println(c.getName());
        }

}
}
```

So my problem is in the showCoins() method. I want to print out the contents of the ArrayList, coins. The code compiles but when I run it nothing happens. All other methods are working fine.
This class is in connection with another, which I will post below.

```
public class MyCoins
{
private String myName;
private int myValue;

/**
 * default constructor for MyCoins class.
 */
public MyCoins(String name, int value)
{
    myName = name;
    myValue = value;
}

/**
 * Non-default constructor for MyCoins class.
 */
public MyCoins(int value)
{
    myValue = value;
    if(value == 1)
        myName = new String("Penny");
    else if(value == 5)
        myName = new String("Nickel");
    else if(value == 10)
        myName = new String("Dime");
    else if(value == 25)
        myName = new String("Quarter");
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enter the value of a US coin.");
}

/**
 * Returns the current value of coins as an integer.
 */
public int getValue()
{
    return myValue;
}

/**
 * Returns myName as a String.
 */
public String getName()
{
    return myName;
}
}
```

Comment: There is no main function.  How are we supposed to know what exactly you're doing wrong?

Comment: You're creating a new, empty `ArrayList` as  the first line of that method, discarding the current one. Therefore ... there's nothing to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an `ArrayList` but didn't add anything to it. So getting an iterator and iterating iterates over nothing. So nothing to print.

```
coins = new ArrayList<MyCoins>();
Iterator<MyCoins> itr = coins.iterator();
```

Maybe you were trying to refer to the `coins` instance field. In that case, get rid of

```
coins = new ArrayList<MyCoins>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `coins = new ArrayList<MyCoins>();` from your `showCoins()` method. It replaces the list of coins currently in your purse by an empty list.

Comment: Downvoted for spoonfeeding without explaining the issue at hand

Comment: @fstd That's a bit soon to downvote, already amended.